# Fill NaN for each different index level with value in the previous or next cell depending on the sequence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-indexed DataFrame storing indicators about countries year by year. But some years' data is missing. I'd like to forward-fill or back-fill the NaNs with the first cell value available in chronological order of the same country.

For instance starting from this DataFrame:

```
                        GDP     Life expectancy     Population
                        
country      date
BRA       1959-01-01    123          68                 3M
          1960-01-01    189          69                 4M
          1961-01-01    191          71                 Nan
          1962-01-01    NaN          Nan                Nan

COL       1960-01-01    Nan          Nan                Nan
          1961-01-01    Nan          Nan                Nan
          1962-01-01    234          72                 3M
          1963-01-01    544          68                 4M
```

For country (index) BRA it will back-fill the NaNs since the first data available belongs to a previous cell.

For country (index) COL, instead, it will forward-fill the NaNs since the first data available belongs to the next cell:

```
                        GDP     Life expectancy     Population
country      date       
BRA       1959-01-01    123          68                 3M    
          1960-01-01    189          69                 4M
          1961-01-01    191          71                 4M
          1962-01-01    191          71                 4M

COL       1960-01-01    234          72                 3M
          1961-01-01    234          72                 3M
          1962-01-01    234          72                 3M
          1963-01-01    544          68                 4M
```

Comment: `df.groupby('country').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())`?

Comment: 'country' and 'date' are multi-indexes and not actual columns

Comment: All the Pandas version I've worked with (`0.24+` ) accepts level name in `groupby`. You can try `level=0` instead of `'country'` if you prefers...

Comment: Okay you are right it actually works in both the ways. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided in the firs comment:

```
df.groupby('country').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```